# how to draw a rectangle box on an image; wxPython?

Tags: wxpython

I am trying to draw a rectangle on an image. the image has been set up on a panel.

I have tried using wx.PaintDC, it works on the panel and gets rid of the image. I want to have the rectangle on an image.

```
import wx

class window (wx.Frame):
    def __init__ (self, parent, id):
        wx.Frame.__init__ (self, parent, id, "Solitair", size = (1200, 800))
        self.add_menubar()
        self.panel = wx.Panel(self)
        img = 'background.jpg'
        bmp = wx.Image(img, wx.BITMAP_TYPE_ANY).ConvertToBitmap()
        self.bitmap = wx.StaticBitmap(self.panel, -1, bmp, (0,0))

        self.bitmap.Bind(wx.EVT_PAINT, self.drowRec)

    def drowRec(self, event):
        dc = wx.PaintDC(self.bitmap)
        dc.SetPen(wx.Pen('green', 5, wx.SOLID))
        dc.SetBrush(wx.Brush('green', wx.TRANSPARENT))
        dc.DrawRectangle(100, 50, 150, 200)
```

The rectangle supposed to be on an image panel, not on the actual empty panel.

please help.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Take a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20287152/wxpython-draw-text-onto-existing-bitmap-or-image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adapting your code and the code at [wxPython draw text onto EXISTING bitmap or image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20287152/wxpython-draw-text-onto-existing-bitmap-or-image)

we can quickly knock up:

```
import wx

class window (wx.Frame):
    def __init__ (self, parent, id):
        wx.Frame.__init__ (self, parent, id, "Solitair", size = (1200, 800))
        self.panel = wx.Panel(self)
        img = 'wxPython.jpg'
        self.bmp = wx.Image(img, wx.BITMAP_TYPE_ANY).ConvertToBitmap()
        self.bitmap = wx.StaticBitmap(self.panel, -1, self.bmp)
        self.drowRec(None)

    def drowRec(self, event):
        dc = wx.MemoryDC(self.bmp)
        dc.SetPen(wx.Pen('green', 5, wx.SOLID))
        dc.SetBrush(wx.Brush('green', wx.TRANSPARENT))
        dc.DrawRectangle(20, 20, 60, 60)
        del dc
        self.bitmap.SetBitmap(self.bmp)

app = wx.App(False)
frame = window(None, -1)
frame.Show()
app.MainLoop()
```

[image]

Comment: excellent answer!  I struggled with this topic for hours until I ran into your post that laid out out so cleanly.